# How to mimic DefaultRoute in React Router 1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So, switching to the latest React Router (1.0.0RC3).  I have run into a piece of old functionality that I can't find how to replicate with the new 1.0 API.

In my Router, I always render a top-level `App` component, then a second-level `Layout` component, then a `Page` component.  In the old React Router, I didn't have to put a `path` property on a `Route`, so I could "group" certain routes to have a parent component without adding another level to my url.

Below, you'll see that when hitting the `/` route, I try to load `App`, `DefaultLayout`, and `Home`.  However, it won't render `DefaultLayout` without an explicit `path` property.  So if I put `path="app"` on my default layout, it works, but I'm trying to not change my homepage route if possible.

I've tried leaving path off, putting an absolute path, using nested `IndexRoutes` (doesn't work).  Is there still a way to do this in RR 1.0?

```js
export const routes = (
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route component={DefaultLayout}> // Requires `path` Here
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path="about" component={About} />
                <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="careers" component={Careers} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="blog" component={BlogLayout}>
                <IndexRoute component={BlogHome} />
                <Route path="posts/:post_name" component={BlogPost} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your routes should look like:

```jsx
export const routes = (
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
        <Route component={App}>
            <Route path="/" component={DefaultLayout}> // Requires `path` Here
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path="about" component={About} />
                <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="careers" component={Careers} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="blog" component={BlogLayout}>
                <IndexRoute component={BlogHome} />
                <Route path="posts/:post_name" component={BlogPost} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: This doesn't render anything unfortunately.